# How to test that some code doesn't compile in C++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, testing, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unit test compile-time error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605915/unit-test-compile-time-error)

I'm wondering if its possible to write a kind of unit test which will verify that a given code **doesn't** compile.

For example, I have a template class:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp>

struct bar_base {};

template <typename T>
class foo 
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(::boost::is_base_of<T, bar_base>::value);
};
```

So, the test should succeed with:

```
struct bar_derived : bar_base {};
foo<bar_derived> f;
```

but should fail with:

```
struct bar_other {};
foo<bar_other> f;
```

Any ideas how to achieve such a behaviour? (For now, I have to uncomment the failing code and verify manually that there are compile errors - I want to avoid that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost does have compilation tests, and they do this by simply putting each of these tests into a single source-file and then try to compile each of these. [Boost.Build](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/) supports [special commands to run tests](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/builtins/testing.html), which include testing if a file compiles or not.

Answer (score 1):

The gist of it would be that you would run a normal "should fail" unittest, but instead of running your compiled program, you run a compiler on an example that should fail.

Eg on gtest, this would be a "death test" on the compiler. http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_AdvancedGuide#Death_Tests

Comment: how to do that? The link doesn't talk about that.