# Automatic testing for non compilable code

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I use `std::enable_if`, `if constexpr`, ... to guard the usage of some template functions, classes, ...

The main goal is to give compile errors when the template arguments provided are not supported.

Does anyone has a solution to incorporate some construction that 'should not compile' into an automatic test system?

Here is some stupid example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool>
fuzzzyCompere(T a, T b)
{
    return std::abs(a - b) < 2 * (std::abs(a) + std::abs(a)) * std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << fuzzzyCompere(1.2, 3.2) << '\n';
    // std::cout << fuzzzyCompere(1, 3) << '\n'; // how to test that it doesn't compile

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/lqE7eKTJOFxGDrov

Comment: Have a file that should not compile, try to compile it, fail the test if it compiles?

Comment: Maybe `static_assert`?

Comment: I will provide an example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/lqE7eKTJOFxGDrov

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547831/assert-that-code-does-not-compile

Comment: Related to [expected-build-failure-tests-in-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155619/expected-build-failure-tests-in-cmake).